# How to know when the user has finished resizing the window?

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt5, qt5

I am programming myself a PDF Reader for the fun and giggles however I am having trouble when the window is being resized. The problem is the following: When the window is being resized while a PDF is loaded, the PDF is being rendered again to match the new window sizes, however the resizeEvent is being called several times thus the render funtion is being called multible times, which is incredibly inefficient and causes lags. Is there a way to have the program notice whenever the resizeEvent is fully done and then call the render function? Solutions in both Python and C++ are welcome

Comment: Please add whatever you tried so far

Comment: When you receive a resizeEvent the resizing has already happened, the problem is that some widget might receive it repeatedly (or even recursively) due to their contents (this usally happens when scrollbars are in play). How are you showing the documents? Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Disclaimer

The below solution is an answer to the question **How to know when the user has finished resizing the window?**, which is clear enough to be answered.

However, I believe you have a XY problem. The slow rendering you are experiencing might be due to using the wrong technology, but there is no way to tell without seeing the code. I suggest you to describe your rendering problem in another question, supporting it with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

### Solution

My approach to such a problem would be to:

1. Act before the resize happens

As @musicamante writes in the comments:

> When you receive a resizeEvent the resizing has already happened

The way to overtake [`QWidget::resizeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) is using [`QObject::event`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#event) instead and watch for [`QEvent::type`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#type) [`QResizeEvent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum).

2. Try to distinguish between *programatic resize*, i.e. calling [`QWidget::resize`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#size-prop) and *user resize*, i.e. by dragging a window 's edge

[`QEvent::spontaneous`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#spontaneous) could be used for this purpose, as it:

> Returns true if the event originated outside the application (a system event); otherwise returns false.

If the event is non-spontaneous (*programatic resize*), allow the generation of a `resizeEvent` to set the initial size of the complex widget. For a spontaneous event (*user resize*), prevent the generation of a `resizeEvent` and handle the size of the complex widget manually

4. Get the **exact** moment the user has finished resizing the window, instead of using a timer, as @G.M. (which I highly respect by the way) suggested

Here the `NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease` event type might come in handy.

It does not necessarly mean, that the user is resizing the window. This event type is generated also be dragging the window. However, in this case that does not affect the solution.

**Note:** Do not add the complex widget to any layout, as it would break the manual size handling.

### Example

Here is an example in C++ I have written for you in order to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QResizeEvent>
#include <QFormLayout>
#include <QLineEdit>

class MainWindow : public QWidget
{
    QWidget *m_complexWidget;
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) :
        QWidget(parent),
        m_complexWidget(new QWidget(this)) {
        auto *form = new QFormLayout(m_complexWidget);

        for (int n = 0; n < 20; n++)
            form->addRow(tr("Property ") + QString::number(n),
                         new QLineEdit(this));

        resize(400, 400);
    }

    bool event(QEvent *event) override {
        switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::NonClientAreaMouseButtonRelease:
            // The widget is resized at the end of a resize
            m_complexWidget->resize(size());
            break;
        case QEvent::Resize:
            // Prevent generation of a resize event
            if (event->spontaneous())
                return false;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        return QWidget::event(event);
    }

protected:
    void resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *event) override {
        // The widget's size is set to the initial size of the window
        m_complexWidget->resize(event->size());
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example and the explenation. I'll try this later today. I had another idea on how to prevent the resizeEvent from being called several times: Deactivating the resizing animation.

Comment: My rendering not optimized yet, I will do that later. My rendering problem at the moment is, taht i render the whole PDF at the same time (which obviously is stupid) but I will fix that problem this weekend probably

Comment: @Mettigel4_1 As I've said, your real problem is not with the resizing. Please, follow the suggestion in my answer and post another question with enough details, so the real problem could be identified and a solution could be proposed. As for the resizing, if you try the example, it works perfectly, so I suggest you to consider accepting and/or upvoting my answer.

Comment: I'll work on it thank you

Comment: The problem is partly in the resizing because there is no point of rendering the pdf 3 times because I click on the resize my window button. I am well aware of my rendering problem and I am already fixing it

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your class is named `PDF_reader` you can use a single-shot `QTimer` to notify you when the widget hasn't been resized for a specific length of time -- say 1 second -- and only update the widget if that timer is inactive.

A simple example base on `QLabel` might look something like...

```
class PDF_reader: public QLabel {
  using super      = QLabel;
  using this_class = PDF_reader;
public:
  PDF_reader ()
    : super("Some text goes here")
    {
      m_timer.setSingleShot(true);
      m_timer.setInterval(1000);
      connect(&m_timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, [this]{ update(); });
    }
  virtual void resizeEvent (QResizeEvent *event) override
    {
      m_timer.stop();
      m_timer.start();
    }
  virtual void paintEvent (QPaintEvent *event) override
    {
      if (!m_timer.isActive()) {
        super::paintEvent(event);
      }
      event->accept();
    }
private:
  QTimer m_timer;
};
```

Comment: I would rather not se a timer, it is a work around not a solution in my opinion. But thank you for the example